# Delegate Method Protocol Not Working - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am working on a `splitView` application for my `iPad`. I have implemented a `UIButton` called as `Upload`. On clicking on it, a `UITableView` appears inside a `UIPoverController`. On clicking on any of the contents, I want to display some respective site in my `UIwebView` in `UIDetailView`. For this I have implemented a `delegate method protocol`. I have used the following lines of code in `UploadTableViewController.h` file::

```
@protocol UploadTableViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)selected:(NSString *)his;
@end


 @interface UploadSpaceTableViewController : UITableViewController{
id<UploadSpaceTableViewDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (retain) id delegate;
@end
```

In the corresponding `.m` file I have used the following lines of code ::

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (delegate != nil) {
    NSString *hisSelected = [keys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@ lolwa", hisSelected);
    [delegate selected:hisSelected];
}

}
```

in the `.m` file of class where I have implemented the function `Selected`, the code is ::

```
- (void)selected:(NSString *)Key {    
  NSLog(@"hello");    
  [self.UploadSpaceTableViewPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}


-(IBAction)uploadpressed:(id)sender{  
Upload.delegate = self;
self.Upload = [[UploadSpaceTableViewController alloc] 
                         initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.UploadTableViewPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
                                initWithContentViewController:UploadSpace];               

[self.UploadTableViewPopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender 
                                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
 }
```

However, I am unable to get `hello` (written in the function `Selected`) `NSLogged` in gdb. This is the first time that I am using this `delegate method protocol`. I am unable to sort this out. Can someone help me out ? Thanks and regards.

Comment: In the declaration the delegate method is called `Selected` and yet you actually call `keySelected`?

Comment: in your delegate .h : have you declared it conforms to the `UploadTableViewDelegate`? have you set your delegate in your delegates .m like `uploadSpaceTVC.delegate = self` ?

Comment: @Pfitz .. no .. where should I decalre it ?? in `viewDidLoad` method ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegation works like this

- declare a protocol - you have done this
- declare a delegate property - you have done this
- In the class which you want to be the delegate say it conforms to the protocoll

  `@interface MyClass : MySuperClass <UploadTableViewDelegate>`
- set the delegate property so the delegate class can get the delegate messages

  `uploadSpaceTVC.delegate = self;`
- call the delegate methods in your non delegate class (`UploadSpaceTableViewController`)

  `[self.delegate selected:@"test"];`

Comment: where or in which method and class should I set my delegate as `uploadSpaceTVC.delegate = self;` ??

Comment: i recommend when you initialize the class like `UploadSpaceTableViewController *uploadSpaceTVC = [[UploadSpaceTableViewController alloc] init];` - in the line after this

Comment: hmm .. you are right. I have declared the `delegate` in the wrong line as you can see in my code. `Upload.delegate = self;` should be written just below the line of `self.Upload = [[UploadSpaceTableViewController alloc]                   initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];` . I rectified it and it worled. Thanks a lot. Can you also explain me the reason ??

Comment: Upload would be NULL in your current implementation, so setting it's delegate (which you are retaining for no reason), would result in nil.

Answer (score 5):

`[delegate keySelected:hisKeySelected];` is your first problem.  You don't declare a delegate method named `-keySelected:`, you declare a delegate method named `-Selected:`.

Your second problem is the fact that you are most definitely not the delegate of your table view.  In order for a delegate method like `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to be called, you must be the table's delegate.

PS, don't begin instances, or method names, with an uppercase letter.  In ObjC, uppercase letters indicate a class.

EDIT:  this is what your `UploadSpaceTableViewController` header should look like:

```
@protocol UploadTableViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)selected:(NSString *)his;
@end

@interface UploadSpaceTableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UploadSpaceTableViewDelegate>delegate; //delegates are weak!!!
@end
```

And the .m, I will skip a lot of the unnecessary stuff:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
}
//other code
```

Furthermore, your delegate is declared retain, which is an absolutel No-No in ObjC.  Declare is weak if using ARC, or assign if not.

You are also producing a nil delegate in in your `-uploadPressed:` method by setting it before you explicitly own or initialize the object.  Here's how it should look:

```
self.Upload = [[UploadSpaceTableViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
Upload.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I rectified it. sorry .. it is selected actually. Still, I am not getting `hello` or `lolwa` `NSLogged` in `gdb`.

Comment: For that you need to be the delegate and data source of your table view.  If using IB, drag the delegate and datasource outlets from the table to files owner.  If in code, declare your intent to conform with angle brackets <>, then set `self.tableView.delegate = self; self.tableView.dataSource =self`

Comment: where should I declare these ? in `UploadPressed` method ??

Comment: No, UploadSpaceTableViewController needs to be the delegate of its table

Comment: I think I have declared it in the line `Upload.delegate = self;`. Here, `Upload` is an instance of `UploadTableViewController` class.

Comment: No, that makes you the delegate of the `UploadSpaceTableViewController` class.  Now the `UploadSpaceTableViewController` needs to be the delegate of its table.

Comment: I am getting all the more confused .. can you tell me specifically as to where should I declare these ??

Comment: I've edited in an example.  You have many fundamental errors in your code.